# Add onlick event to NSView programatically without subclassing

Tags: swift, onclick, nsview

I create a bunch of NSviews programmatically. How can I set the function that is performend when the NSView is clicked?

For NSButton you can use `button.addTarget`. For NSView this doesn't exist however...

Thanks!

Comment: `NSButton` doesn't have a `addTarget` method either. Have you tried a `NSClickGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: That is perfect, thanks.